# How to use axios response in other const?

Tags: reactjs, axios

i am new in react js, i have made function to call database value using axios. I put the response in a function and const. I already call the function and want to use the const inside the function in other const, but i get undefined error.

Here is my code in js :

```
import axios from 'axios';

/*axios.get('http://localhost:3001/process')
     .then((response) => {
       console.log(response); // Hasil yang benar
       return response;
     });*/

     const getValueAxios = async () => {
      try {
         const resGet = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/process')
         console.log(resGet)
      } catch (error) {
         console.log(error);
      }
   }

   getValueAxios();

const eChart = {
  series: [
    {
      name: "Sales",
      data: [resGet[0].value, resGet[1].value, resGet[2].value, resGet[3].value, resGet[4].value, resGet[5].value, resGet[6].value, resGet[7].value, resGet[8].value, resGet[9].value, resGet[10].value, resGet[11].value],
      color: "#fff",
    },
  ],

  options: {
    chart: {
      type: "bar",
      width: "100%",
      height: "auto",

      toolbar: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        horizontal: false,
        columnWidth: "55%",
        borderRadius: 5,
      },
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    stroke: {
      show: true,
      width: 1,
      colors: ["transparent"],
    },
    grid: {
      show: true,
      borderColor: "#ccc",
      strokeDashArray: 2,
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: [
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "Mar",
        "Apr",
        "May",
        "Jun",
        "Jul",
        "Aug",
        "Sep",
        "Oct",
        "Nov",
        "Dec",
      ],
      labels: {
        show: true,
        align: "right",
        minWidth: 0,
        maxWidth: 160,
        style: {
          colors: [
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    yaxis: {
      labels: {
        show: true,
        align: "right",
        minWidth: 0,
        maxWidth: 160,
        style: {
          colors: [
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
            "#fff",
          ],
        },
      },
    },

    tooltip: {
      y: {
        formatter: function (val) {
          return "Rp. " + val + " millions";
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

export default eChart;
```

it give me error like this " Line 24:14:  'resGet' is not defined  no-undef" in here :

```
[resGet[0].value, resGet[1].value, resGet[2].value, resGet[3].value, resGet[4].value, resGet[5].value, resGet[6].value, resGet[7].value, resGet[8].value, resGet[9].value, resGet[10].value, resGet[11].value]
```

Comment: `resGet` is defined inside the `getValueAxios()` function so it will not be available outside that function. Declare `resGet`  outside the `getValueAxios()` function and it should work.

Comment: how to declare ? can give me some example ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would like to export a function `getEChart()` instead of the `eChart` object because the `eChart` object is dependent on API response. Then you can call this function using wherever you need `eChart`.

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const getValueAxios = async () => {
  try {
    let resGet = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/process')
    console.log(resGet)
    return resGet;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

const getEChart = async () => {
  const resGet = await getValueAxios();

  const eChart = {
    series: [{
      name: "Sales",
      data: [resGet[0].value, resGet[1].value, resGet[2].value, resGet[3].value, resGet[4].value, resGet[5].value, resGet[6].value, resGet[7].value, resGet[8].value, resGet[9].value, resGet[10].value, resGet[11].value],
      color: "#fff",
    }, ],

    options: {
      chart: {
        type: "bar",
        width: "100%",
        height: "auto",

        toolbar: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          horizontal: false,
          columnWidth: "55%",
          borderRadius: 5,
        },
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      stroke: {
        show: true,
        width: 1,
        colors: ["transparent"],
      },
      grid: {
        show: true,
        borderColor: "#ccc",
        strokeDashArray: 2,
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: [
          "Jan",
          "Feb",
          "Mar",
          "Apr",
          "May",
          "Jun",
          "Jul",
          "Aug",
          "Sep",
          "Oct",
          "Nov",
          "Dec",
        ],
        labels: {
          show: true,
          align: "right",
          minWidth: 0,
          maxWidth: 160,
          style: {
            colors: [
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      yaxis: {
        labels: {
          show: true,
          align: "right",
          minWidth: 0,
          maxWidth: 160,
          style: {
            colors: [
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
              "#fff",
            ],
          },
        },
      },

      tooltip: {
        y: {
          formatter: function(val) {
            return "Rp. " + val + " millions";
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };

  return eChart;
};

export default getEChart;
```

Comment: heloo, sory for my late response. Already tried your code and it give me error like this "Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `series` is marked as required in `r`, but its value is `undefined`."

Comment: Can you show me how you implemented this? If you can create a small replicable demo on codesandbox then that would be perfect.